# service does not stop in android

Tags: android, service

I have developed an android app which enables location service and sends data to server. I want to put some control on the app like starting and stopping location service.

I implemented `AlarmManager` to re-start the service after a certain time. But when I uncheck the `ToggleButton` to stop this service, it does not work. The service does not stop. It's running and sending data to server continuously after stopping service.

I added the `onDestroy()` method of my service and the `on/off` checking codes below.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
```

service on/off controlling code

```
tracking.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true){

                    AlarmRecurrer loc = new AlarmRecurrer(getApplicationContext());
                    loc.setRecurringAlarmSchedule(getApplicationContext());

                }
                if (isChecked == false){

                    Intent locationService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
                    getApplicationContext().stopService(locationService);
                }

            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me the possible way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have to stop your Timer or AlarmManager you're using to run the service within onDestroy() of service.

> A service can be stopped by calling its stopSelf() method, or by calling Context.stopService().

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife) for some more information.